# Run MSSQL and run script on it in docker

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I want to run the MSSQL database, then run a script that creates some tables in it.
In the end I want the resulting container to be an SQL Server instance with a pre-created database.
My current dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# ENTRYPOINT ./opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

CMD python3 /usr/src/app/apply_schema.py
```

The problem is that MSSQL doesn't run this way, only the python script runs (and predictably fails to connect to database).

How can I run MSSQL first, then run the script?

Comment: What is in apply_schema.py?

Comment: I gave an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613259/1737862). Maybe it helps you.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu SQLAlchemy connects to the database, runs create_all() to make a few tables. But I think its not important for the question, since it could be anything instead of that script.

Comment: @JodyT seems like what I need! I will try it and report back

Comment: @JodyT it worked! Please post an answer here so I can accept it

Comment: Why don't you run your script inside the running docker container after the server was started: `docker exec -ti container_name python3 /usr/src/app/apply_schema.py`

Comment: @KlausD. I can, but I want to decouple schema from my apps. If I run an app I can just run a docker container with the db and be sure that the db has up-to-date schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot log into SQL Server in mssql-server-linux container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453969/cannot-log-into-sql-server-in-mssql-server-linux-container)