# Login fails for SA sql server linux docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I try to use sql server on docker, linux. I start the container like this:

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password="12345qwerASDF" -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y --name sql-server --hostname sql-server  microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

When I try to connect, all I get is "Login failed for user 'sa'"

Tried with different password, with and without double and single quotes...

Comment: Is connection successful with `mssql` ? Also are you using Powershell or linux shell ?

Comment: No connection successful. Using powershell.

Comment: I see in the documentation that the sa_password should also be enclosed in quotes, for example docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot log into SQL Server in mssql-server-linux container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453969/cannot-log-into-sql-server-in-mssql-server-linux-container)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I got it to work:

```
docker run --name sqlserver --hostname sqlserver -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwd!!" -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

I guess it should be MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD and not SA_PASSWORD

The documentation isn't clear in that part...

Comment: I found that MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD and SA_PASSWORD were interchangeable. I'm running Docker 19.03.1 and found that I didn't need quotes or single quotes around the environment variables ```docker run --name sqlserver -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwd! -d -p:1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu

Comment: If you are a complete beginner here is how to run SQL Server in Docker https://thecodeframework.com/run-sql-server-inside-a-docker-container/

Comment: Damn, what an absurd... Thanks for your insight Erik Lindstrom!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. Stop the sql server services running in your local. Then You can login to sql server(linux) via docker(dbeaver)

1-) I got the error

[image]

2-) Stop the sql server services running in your local(Task Manager -> Services)

[image: ![enter image description here]

3-) Then You can login to sql server(linux) via docker(dbeaver)

[image]

I hope it was helpful

Answer (score 3):

Your password `12345qwerASDF` doesn't meet [complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017). Try adding a non-alphanumeric characters such as exclamation point (`!`).

To check for errors, run: `docker logs ID` (where `ID` is container ID from `docker ps`).

Comment: Sry same result...
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem with this notes

1. In formal doc used SA_PASSWORD !!!, but MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD is true (Microsoft team, what are doing?!!!!)
2. As a docker "[Configuration/Requirements for Microsoft SQL Server][1]" said: " A strong system administrator (SA) password: At least 8 characters including uppercase, lowercase letters, base-10 digits and/or non-alphanumeric symbols."
3. In Linux, use single quote for define password .
4. Be sure, before you run "docker run .." ,  the **volume** of "**data**" which you mount from host to container must be clean (if you have it!).

---

Here is a sample of “docker run” for creation Microsoft SQL Server container.

```
docker run  
-e ACCEPT_EULA=Y 
-e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD='Mssql!Passw0rd' 
-e MSSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/opt/mssql/data  
-e MSSQL_PID='Developer' 
-e MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433 
-p 1433:1433  
-v /var/opt/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data  
-v /var/opt/mssql/log:/var/opt/mssql/log  
-v /var/opt/mssql/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets 
--name mssql_2017 
-d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

---

for checking an instance of SQL Server ...

```
docker exec -it mssql_2017 /bin/bash
cd /opt/mssql-tools/bin/
./sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Mssql!Passw0rd'
select @@version
go
```

I hope this hints can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened to me but the problem was I had a windows desktop version of MSSQL and I forgot to stop the service before connecting to the docker version.

Comment: how did you stop the service?

Comment: @whisk Press Win+R keyboard shortcut together. When the Run dialog arrives, put services.msc in its text field then click ok. you will find list of services find mssql server from the list right click on it then click stop.

Answer (score 1):

For docker-compose file 
i was facing problem with sa user login failed i fix it by adding 
  depends_on:
   - db

here's my full version of docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
 colour-api: 
  build: .
  environment:
   DBServer: "ms-sql-server"
  ports:
  - "8080:80" 
  depends_on:
   - ms-sql-server
 ms-sql-server:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
  environment:
   ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
   MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "Pa55w0rd2019" 
  ports: 
   - "1444:1433"
```

Follow this link for more details

https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "sa_password=12345qwerASDF" -p 1433:1433 --name sql-server --hostname sql-server -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

> IMPORTANT NOTE: If you are using PowerShell on Windows to run these
>   commands use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Source : https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/

Comment: @ErikLindstrom Does your password contain '@' symbol ? (I doubt that 1234.... is the real password)

Comment: 1234qwerASDF is the real password, just trying to get it to work, no special characters in pwd

Answer (score 0):

The docker volume used for the mssql service could be corrupted.

In a docker setup using mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
I have encountered a similar problem. Although I had no problem
connecting to the server from a container built from the command line the issue persisted for the docker container.

Removing the volume and recreating the container did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

docker run --name SQLServer -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=“Yourpassword” -e MSSQL_PID="Express" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Comment: Can you explain your answer and format it ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).